# Find longest substring of 1s

Tags: algorithm

On the input we have a string if `0s` and `1s`, for example `0111010100110`, in output  we want to get index of first element in longest substring of `1s`, at this example we are expecting to get `1`.

First, and last, idea that came to me mind is to iterate through whole string in order to find the longest string this will take `O(n)` which is good, but in assignment - expected time-complexity was `O(logn)`. So the question is following, is there is some algorithm to find this in `O(logn)` or it was just a typo?

Comment: How can it be O(log n)?  You can't know if a sequence of 1s is contiguous unless you inspect every element of it, which is inherently linear time.

Comment: Well yeah, I thought the same, but still it was bothering me, thanks

Comment: Hmm you need to inspect every element in sequince but you don't need inspect every element in array, for example if you already find sequence of length x you don't need to inspect space between two zeroes if they are closer than x. May be it really allow to make a bit faster than linear average algorithm. Still in some cases, to example if there is only one 1 in string it's impossible to find it faster than in linear time.

Comment: @Lurr consider longest array of 1s is in length of K then what you suggest in best case(and I think that base case is impossible though) have O(n/k) and that has nothing to do with O(lg n) I really think this is impossible!